# ruby issue taking single or multiple arguments at once

Tags: ruby

I am having issues with making the a "repeat" method take one OR two arguments, I think my code is taking two.

```
def repeat(whatever, n)

    print ([whatever]*n).join(' ')
end
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to do when only one argument is specified?

Comment: @matti i wanted it to print something like hello hello, the code i have here can print a number of these such as hello hello hello

Answer (score 1):

Make the second argument a default

```
def repeat(whatever, n=1)
    print ([whatever]*n.join(' ')
end
```

So you can call

```
repeat("hello", 2)
repeat("hello")
```

Comment: when i tried this on my ruby prompt i got the following error: failure/error:repeat("hello").should == "hello hello" expected: "hello hello" got: nil (using ==)

Comment: @user1762229 remove the `print` and your specs would pass